# Regex does not work properly on Turkish Characters

Tags: c#, regex, character

I have a problem with a regular expression. I wrote some code to check if there is a match on the text like ordering number. And test my regex on [Regexr](http://regexr.com) . For example the user wrote "3'üncü" and the regex does not match. But if the user writes 9'uncu then regex gets a match. My regex is;

```
([0-9]*)(([-/.]|[\w])([n][c][ıIiİuUüÜ]))|([0-9]*)(([-/.]|[\w])([ıIiİuUüÜ][n][c][ıIiİuUüÜ]))
```

And I can say, the regex caught Turkish characters, but not English characters. What is wrong with that? Thanks for help.

Comment: what language are you using?

Comment: To match all Turkish and Latin (and all Unicode BMP) letters, you might as well use `\p{L}+`. What is your input like?

Comment: http://regexr.com/ is not designed for .net, use http://regexstorm.net instead.

Comment: @stribizhev my input like "Bu sene sınıfta 3'üncü oldum". I'll try your solution.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte i don't think the problem is the website.

Comment: Maybe just use `[\w.'-]*` or [`\b[\w.'-]*\b`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb%5b%5cw.%27-%5d*%5cb&i=Bu+sene+s%c4%b1n%c4%b1fta+3%27%c3%bcnc%c3%bc+oldum)? You can use `\w` to match Unicode numbers, letters and underscore in C# regex. I just do not understand if you are trying to match all words, or just the words starting with number + apostrophe or what. Please clear that out.

Comment: I'm just trying to get if there is any part like "3'üncü" on a long text.

Comment: And what is specific about it? Because it begins with a digit, then follows an apostrophe, then follow some characters that include Turkish letters? Try [`\b[0-9]*([-'/.]|\w)(?:[n][c][ıIiİuUüÜ]|[ıIiİuUüÜ][n][c]\w)\b`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb%5b0-9%5d*(%5b-%27%2f.%5d%7c%5cw)(%3f%3a%5bn%5d%5bc%5d%5b%c4%b1Ii%c4%b0uU%c3%bc%c3%9c%5d%7c%5b%c4%b1Ii%c4%b0uU%c3%bc%c3%9c%5d%5bn%5d%5bc%5d%5cw)%5cb&i=3%27%c3%bcnc%c3%bc)

Comment: That is the reason I posted this question, I did not understand how it works or not. it does not caught "3'üncü" but it caught "9'uncu". What is the difference? and what is my mistake?

Comment: From what I see your regex matches both `3'üncü` and `9'uncu` [in a similar, partial way](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%5b0-9%5d*)((%5b-%2f.%5d%7c%5b%5cw%5d)(%5bn%5d%5bc%5d%5b%c4%b1Ii%c4%b0uU%c3%bc%c3%9c%5d))%7c(%5b0-9%5d*)((%5b-%2f.%5d%7c%5b%5cw%5d)(%5b%c4%b1Ii%c4%b0uU%c3%bc%c3%9c%5d%5bn%5d%5bc%5d%5b%c4%b1Ii%c4%b0uU%c3%bc%c3%9c%5d))&i=3%27%c3%bcnc%c3%bc%60+and+9%27uncu). The reason is missing `'` in the character class `[-/.]`. Also, the regex pattern can be reduced since there is no need to repeat the beginning part the second time, just use grouping.

Comment: Also please check [this `\b[0-9]*[-'/.](?:\w[n][c][ıIiİuUüÜ]|[ıIiİuUüÜ][n][c]\w)\b` regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb%5b0-9%5d*%5b-%27%2f.%5d(%3f%3a%5cw%5bn%5d%5bc%5d%5b%c4%b1Ii%c4%b0uU%c3%bc%c3%9c%5d%7c%5b%c4%b1Ii%c4%b0uU%c3%bc%c3%9c%5d%5bn%5d%5bc%5d%5cw)%5cb&i=Bu+sene+s%c4%b1n%c4%b1fta+3%27%c3%bcnc%c3%bc+oldum). Or even [`\b[0-9]*[-'/.](?:\wnc[ıIiİuUüÜ]|[ıIiİuUüÜ]nc\w)\b`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb%5b0-9%5d*%5b-%27%2f.%5d(%3f%3a%5cwnc%5b%c4%b1Ii%c4%b0uU%c3%bc%c3%9c%5d%7c%5b%c4%b1Ii%c4%b0uU%c3%bc%c3%9c%5dnc%5cw)%5cb&i=Bu+sene+s%c4%b1n%c4%b1fta+3%27%c3%bcnc%c3%bc+oldum)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Regex works fine.

Here's some code to test it:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;


public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var m = Regex.Match("3'üncü", @"([0-9]*)(([-/.]|[\w])([n][c][ıIiİuUüÜ]))|([0-9]*)(([-/.]|[\w])([ıIiİuUüÜ][n][c][ıIiİuUüÜ]))");
        Console.WriteLine(m.Success);
        Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
True
üncü
```

Here's a [demo](http://ideone.com/2HNHNQ).

It could be that you did not save the .cs file using an appropriate encoding. This is necessary, because the code (the literal string from which you build the Regex) contains characters which are not representable in the default encoding (which, in my case, is *Western European, CP 1252*).

To save the file as Unicode, select from the menu *File* -> *Advanced Save Options* and select the *Unicode(UTF-8)* encoding.

Comment: That is true but i think that my regex must not caught only "üncü". Anyway, thanks for helps. I solved my problem with writing another regex.